# AS3 embedding CSV files and reading from them

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, csv

So in a simple arcade/platformer game, I'm making it so I have a .csv text file set out like so:

660, 25, 0

720, 15, 1

etc..

The first number being the x coordinate, the next being the y coordinate and the last being whether the block kills you or not. Loading this data externally is not a problem and works fine but when it comes to actually running the .swf by itself obviously the .csv file is not embedded into it so I cannot access any values from it.

Therefore my question is: **How can I embed a .csv file into my project and then read out 3 values per line into a multi dimensional array with each line denoting a different obstacle?**

(The multi dimensional array being **[obstacleID][0 for x coord/1 for y coord/2 for whether it kills or not]**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to embed a text file in Flash](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/06/24/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-flash/)

then you can try:

```
var csv:embedded_csv = new embedded_csv();
var csvLines:Array = csv.toString().split("\n"); // \n or File.lineSeparator or \r\n

for(i=0; i<csvLines.length; i++)
{
   line:Array = String(csvLines[i]).split(", ");
   x = line[0];
   y = line[1];
   kills = line[2];
   ...
}
```